Distance function to unit fractions — where differentiable?
Define a function $f\colon [0,2] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $$f(x) = \inf\left\{\left| x-\frac{1}{n}\right|: n \in \Bbb N\right\}$$ determine the set of points at which $f$ is differentiable.
My solution:
1: if $a >1$ then:
$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{x-1-(a-1)}{x-a} =1 $
2: if $a = \frac{1}{n_0}$:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{x-\frac{1}{n_0}-0}{x-\frac{1}{n_0}}=1 $$
but
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} \frac{\frac{1}{n_0}-x-0}{x-\frac{1}{n_0}}=-1 $$
3: if $\frac{1}{n_0+1}<a<\frac{1}{n_0}$
suppose that $a = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{n_0}+\frac{1}{n_0+1})$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{\frac{1}{n_0}-x-(\frac{1}{n_0}-a)}{x-a}=-1 $$
but
$$\lim_{{x \to a^-}} \frac{{f(x) - f(a)}}{{x - a}} = \lim_{{x \to a^-}} \frac{{x - \frac{1}{n_0 + 1} - (a - \frac{1}{n_0 + 1})}}{x-a} = 1$$
now suppose that $$  \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{n_0}+\frac{1}{n_0+1})<a<\frac{1}{n_0}$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{\frac{1}{n_0}-x-\frac{1}{n_0}+a}{x-a}=-1 $$
In the same way the derivative exists for $ \frac{1}{n_0+1}<a<\frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{n_0}+\frac{1}{n_0+1})$

My question is: is $f$ differentiable at $x=0$?


Try to show $|f(x)|<x^2$ to study differentiability at $x=1$.

@GEdgar i don't know how to show that. could you help me more?

Consider $x_n=\frac12\big(\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}\big)$. Can you bound $f(x)/x$ by $f(x_n)/x_n$ for $1/(n+1)\le x\le 1/n$?

I've changed the title because the original title strongly suggested you want to know something (presumably a sharp Borel hierarchy result) about the set of points at which an arbitrary function is differentiable.

You failed the initial question: what are the values of $f$? BTW, I can understand that in your convention $0\notin N$ but I have been using the convention $0\in \Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N^*=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ for too long, so I shall stick to that...
Let us first study $f$ before wondering for its derivability.

$1\le x\le 2$: $\forall n\in \Bbb N^*, \frac 1 n \le 1$, so $f(x) = x - 1$
$\frac 34\le x<1$: $\lvert x-1\rvert = 1-x$ while $\forall n\in \Bbb N, n>1
\implies \frac 1 n\le \frac 1 2\implies 0 \le 1 - x\le x-\frac 1 n$ , so $f(x) = 1-x$
$\frac 12<x<\frac 34$: $\lvert x-1\rvert = 1-x\ge\frac 14$, while $\forall x\in \Bbb N, n>2, \left(0\le x-\frac 12\le\frac 1 4\right)\land\left(x-\frac 12\le x-\frac 1n\right)$, so $f(x) = x-\frac 12$

More generaly, we have of course $\forall n\in\Bbb N^*, f\left(\frac 1n\right) = 0$, and in an interval $\left]\frac 1{n+1}; \frac 1n\right[$, we can reproduce the same operation to show that $\frac 1{n+1}< x\le\frac 12\left(\frac 1n +\frac 1{n+1}\right) \implies f(x)=x-\frac 1{n+1}$ and that $\frac 12\left(\frac 1n +\frac 1{n+1}\right)\le x<\frac 1 n\implies f(x) = \frac 1 n-x$
It immediately comes that $f$ is a piecewise linear function and is derivable on $]0; 2[\setminus \left(\left\lbrace\frac 1n, n\in \Bbb N^*\right\rbrace\cup\left\lbrace\frac 12\left(\frac 1n+\frac 1{n+1}\right), n\in\Bbb N^*\right\rbrace\right)$, and that:
$\forall n\in\Bbb N^*, \forall x\in \left]\frac 1{n+1};\frac{\frac 1{n+1}+\frac 1n} 2\right[, f'(x) = 1$ and
$\forall n\in\Bbb N^*, \forall x\in \left]\frac{\frac 1{n+1}+\frac 1n} 2; \frac 1n\right[, f'(x) = -1$

At $0$, we have to go back to the definition of the derivative.
First $f(0) = \inf\{\lvert 0-\frac{1}{n}\lvert; n \in \Bbb N^*\} = 
\inf\{\frac{1}{n}; n \in \Bbb N^*\} = 0$.
Let us consider a (small) $\alpha>0$. If we take $N=\left\lceil\frac 1\alpha\right\rceil$ we have $\forall n\in \Bbb N, n>N \implies \frac 1 n <\alpha$. Let us now take $x$, $0<x<\alpha$ and $n = \left\lfloor\frac 1 x\right\rfloor$. We have $\frac 1{n+1}<x\le\frac 1n$. So we know $0\le f(x)\le f\left(\frac{\frac 1{n+1}+\frac 1 n}2\right) = \frac{\frac 1{n+1}+\frac 1 n}2 - \frac 1{n+1} = \frac 1 2\left(\frac 1 n - \frac 1{n+1}\right) = \frac 1 {2n(n+1)} \le \frac 1{2 N(N+1)}$
We can write $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{f(x)}x \le\frac{\frac 1 {2n(n+1)}}{\frac 1{n+1}} = \frac 1{2n}<\frac 1{2N}<\alpha$.
We have shown that for any $\varepsilon >0$, we can find $\alpha=\frac\varepsilon 2>0$(*) so that $0<x<\alpha \implies 0\le\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}<\varepsilon \implies \left\lvert\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}\right\rvert <\varepsilon$
By definition of the derivative we can conclude that $f$ is right derivable at $0$ and that $f'(0^+) = 0$.

(*)In fact we just need $\alpha\le\frac 1{N}$ with $N=\lceil\frac 1 \varepsilon\rceil$ (thanks to @M.K.Z. for his remark). Because if $\varepsilon \ne\frac 1N$, there will exist $x\in\left]\frac 1N;\varepsilon\right[$. And the above study will not apply to them. But as $\frac\varepsilon 2 \le\frac 1N$, we are safe...

I'm afraid you're mistaken. is f differentiable at $x=0$? that's my question.

In many parts of the world, $0\notin \Bbb N$.

@TedShifrin: I am an old French man and I acknowledge that I had always learned $0\in\Bbb N$. I now know that for some authors $0\notin\Bbb N$. But I still think that OP should have make more explicit that in their notation, $0\notin N$.

@M.K.Z: Please see my edit...

To be honest, most students (and even researchers) doing mathematics in the US do not have the least idea that in France $0$ is considered a natural number. Deal with it. From the context here, it is clear that we’re dealing with only positive integers.

if $$0< x < \alpha$$ then $$\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{\alpha} \rightarrow n= [\frac{1}{x}] \geq [\frac{1}{\alpha}]= N-1$$
so maybe $n=N-1<N$. for this you have to choose $$\delta = \frac{1}{N}$$ instead $$\delta = \alpha$$

@M.K.Z: you are right, of course. I knew that I should not have posted an edit at such a late time ;-) It should now be correct...

Let $\{t_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence such that $t_n>0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}t_n =0$. define $g:N \rightarrow N $ by
$g(n) = [\frac{1}{t_n}]$ we have:
$g(n) \leq \frac{1}{t_n} < g(n)+1  \Longrightarrow 0< \frac{1}{g(n)+1} < t_n \leq \frac{1}{g(n)} $
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{g(n)+1}=0$ because
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}t_n =0$.
$$ 0 < \frac{f(t_n)}{t_n} \leq f(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{g(n)} + \frac{1}{g(n)+1}))(g(n)+1) = \frac{1}{2g(n)} = \frac{1}{g(n)+g(n)} \leq \frac{1}{g(n)+1}
 \Longrightarrow 
 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(t_n)}{t_n}=0$$
so
$$ 0=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
